# How to write an ADODB.RecordSet (made from an Excel Range) to a SQL Server temporary table

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, adodb, temp-tables

Using VBA Excel I generate various ADODB.RecordSet objects. I would like to harness the power of temp table generation in SQL Server, e.g.

```
select * into #temp1 from Test1 --create temporary table on the fly
```

In particular, I'm interested in the automatic column generation, and would like to have have the ability to transfor my RecordSet objects into temporary tables in SQL Server.